# Creating blocks of text which will be able to edit in SonataAdmin and save in database?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I installed to my Symfony2 below bundles:

- SonataAdmin
- SonataUser

I would like to create block which would be able to be edited in admin. I thought that installing of them and using `sonata_block_render` with `sonata.block.service.text` would solve my problem. But there is only short text

> Insert your custom content here

When I can edit that?
Could I make it, that I can edit in Admin Panel?

*Short explenation about what concept I have:*

*I would like to create blocks text/content/html or something similar which would be saved in database and I would be able to edit them in admin panel. Each of block I would be able to "inject" to templates via some helper.*

My question is: Am I going good way to that and what next? If not, what I have to do?

Comment: got the same question, did you found a solution to this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sonata/formatter](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/index.html), the install/usage doc is quite clear.
You can either create a template or create a whole block service that inherites from FormatterBlockService if you want to override the default text "Insert content here". After sonata-formatter installation, the important part is to implement the twig filter that transform the mardown/twig/wathever into rich html in your public website views. This is not the default rendering. See [this comment](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataFormatterBundle/issues/45#issuecomment-37665749) in the Sonata formatter Github repo